# Want to resize terminal windows in python, working but not quite right

Tags: python, terminal, ansi-escape

I'm attempted to resize the terminal window on launch of a python script to ensure the display will be static size. It's working but not quite what I expected. I've tried a few methods:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write("\x1b[8;40;120t")
```

and

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["echo","-e","\x1b[8;40;120t"])
```

and even just

```
print "\x1b[8;40;80t"
```

They all work and resize the real terminal. However, if my terminal is, let's say 25x80 to start, the script starts, it resizes, then exits. It will not execute the rest of the script. I wrapped it in a try/Except and nothing is thrown. Nothing in the syslogs and python -v script.py shows nothing odd. If I execute the script again or at a term size of 40x120 (my target size)..the script runs just fine. Why is exeecuting the ANSI escape exiting python? Furthermore if I run this interactively it works with no issues.
Using Python 2.6.6.

Comment: I've added code tags to your source code, please remember to use the markdown code function to make your question more readable.

Comment: Thank you!, sorry, first time posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to run the following script, and it "works" (Linux Debian / Python 2.6 / gnome-terminal):

```
print "\x1b[8;40;80t"

print "ok"
```

The window is resized and the script execution continue.

---

If you confirm in your case the program stops after resizing, my *guess* would be Python received a signal `SIGWINCH` when the window is resized.

You should try to [add a specific signal handler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal). Something like that:

```
def resizeHandler(signum, frame):
    print "resize-window signal caught"

signal.signal(signal.SIGWINCH, resizeHandler)
```

Comment: This seems to work, I'm not sure why :) but I'll read up on the signal handlers. Thank you!

Comment: So now that I'm "overloading" the SIGWINCH, to do very little, when I start building a curses screen it fails to get the new cols/rows (which I'm presuming is caught on resize with SIGWINCH). I shot myself in the foot. Can I restore the default SIGWINCH handler before calling curses?

Comment: @Ian: To obtain the _current_ signal handler you could use [signal.getsignal(signal.SIGWINCH)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.getsignal). On the other hand, when you _change_ a signal handler with [signal.signal(signalnum, handler)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal) the _previous_ signal handler is returned

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the terminal in cbreak mode for this. Using the term package (easy_install term) this could look like this:

```
from term import opentty, cbreakmode

with opentty() as tty:
    if tty is not None:
        with cbreakmode(tty, min=0):
            tty.write('\033[8;26;81t');

print 'terminal resized'
```

Comment: Would calling curses.cbreak() do the same?