# Resizing terminal window with python on linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I have been unable to find a way to resize the terminal running linux with python 3.x
I am on "Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"

I have only found ways to escape the terminal using character combinations, which does not work on some terminals.

Comment: Can we see what you have tried already?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941885/want-to-resize-terminal-windows-in-python-working-but-not-quite-right this is for windows but on of the posters said if worked on linux

Answer (score 0):

You can try this line of code. It worked for me.

```
row = 20
col = 40
print('\x1b[8;{0};{1}t'.format(row, col), end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: I can report that this works on Ubuntu's Terminal, but only if the Terminal app window is not maximized.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [set_geometry()](https://github.com/antocuni/wmctrl/blob/master/wmctrl.py#L174) from [wmctrl.py](https://github.com/antocuni/wmctrl).

Otherwise you can rely on the [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) command directly.