# Controlling terminal size when running python in terminal

Tags: python, terminal

I am trying to create a text adventure with some ascii art that displays. However when I run it and adjust the terminal size it messes up the ascii characters. Is there a way to add code to my python script to set the size of the terminal screen when I run it on linux and windows?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Want to resize terminal windows in python, working but not quite right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16941885/want-to-resize-terminal-windows-in-python-working-but-not-quite-right)

Comment: Works, but would like to know how I can stop the terminal from being dragged to a new size with the cursor i.e a fixed size!